# How to open a particular form from another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have two excel files(A&B) which has more than two forms and i need to open a particular form from B file by click a button from A file.

As of now Im opening the B file by clicking a button from A. In the B file worksheet open function im opening a form "Camera" only

```html
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Show.camera
End Sub
```

And i want to open an another form "Mobile" from B file by clicking another button from A file. Is it possible ? Can anyone help me out please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool the below code working :) Thanks mielk

```html
Sub callfrm()
Dim wbfrm As Workbook
Set wbfrm = Workbooks.Open("C:\path\to\Book2.xlsm")
Application.Run "'"& wbfrm.Name & "'!showfrm"
set wbfrm = nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add public function for opening *Mobile* form in file B:

```
Public Sub openMobileForm()
    Call Mobile.Show
End Sub
```

Then you need to run this code from file A like that:

```
Call Excel.Application.Run("B.xlsm!openMobileForm")
```

Remember to change B.xlsm in this code to the real name of file B.

Comment: Should i mention the file path ?

Comment: No, only name and extension.

Comment: But its not working got error in line **Call Excel.Application.Run("B.xlsm!openMobileForm") **

Comment: The name of the file with Mobile form is B.xlsm? If not, you need to replace it in the code with the proper name like I said in my answer.

Comment: Now i'm using the above updated code and the run time error "1004" could you help me?